# "typeof" versus "in" for checking the presence of a property in an object

Tags: javascript, object, properties, typeof

I have an object called `foo`. I want to check if it has the property `bar`.

Should I use this:

```
if (typeof foo.bar !== "undefined")
```

Or this:

```
if ("bar" in foo)
```

**Is there any difference?**

Comment: The later look more clear. I don't think there is much difference.

Comment: They have different results...

Answer (score 4):

"typeof" does not care if the property exists or not and it will return undefined even if the property exists but has a value of "undefined"

While, "in" will return true if the property exists and has a value of "undefined"

For an example, the following would return either *true* or *false* depending on which you use:

```
let person = {
  name: 'John',
  age: undefined
}

console.log('age' in person)
// true
console.log(typeof person.age !=="undefined") 
//false
```

Comment: Jonas, maybe you meant to check the type of person.age instead of age?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is like "which one is the 'best' for checking the presence of a property in an object", therefore the latter (`"bar" in foo`) is what you're looking for.

The result of `if("bar" in foo)` is "only do this if there's a 'bar' property in foo" which what you're asking for.

You could also go for `typeof foo.bar != "undefined"` but it would be useless overkill.